# Selecting item from ASP.NET listbox using jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, listbox

Greetings,

I'm trying to select item from asp.net list box then assign it to a text box so when a click on an item from the list box should appear in the text box.

I tried the code listed down but it did not work.
please advice how to do this!!

............................
updated code
..........................

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm3.aspx.cs" Inherits="IMAM_APPLICATION.WebForm3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

       <script type="text/javascript">
           $(function() {
               $("#<%=ListBox.ClientID %>").change(function() {
                   $("#<%=text.ClientID %>").val($(this).val());
               });
           });


    </script>


<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox" runat="server">

 <asp:ListItem Value="one">1</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="two">2</asp:ListItem>

</asp:ListBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="text" runat="server" 
            style = "position:absolute; top: 267px; left: 45px;"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#<%=ListBox.ClientID %>").change(function() {
    $("#<%=text.ClientID %>").val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Replace your `$(document).ready(function() { })` with the above code, and when you change the dropdown, the value will go in the text input, e.g. `one`, or `two`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.


there is a problem that I need to click the text box after I select an item from listbox to see it appear in the text box.


please advice how to solve this problem.